# Logrotation is not running in docker container via cron job

Tags: docker, cron, logrotate

I have a cronjob set to run logrotate inside docker container.

`/etc/crontab` file:

```
30 9    * * *   root    /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/apache2
```

`/etc/logrotate.d/apacha2` file:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        daily
        missing
        rotate 5
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null ; then \
                    /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null; \
                fi;
        endscript
        prerotate
                if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                        run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
                fi; \
        endscript
}
```

Dockerfile:
.../some contents/......
...........
ENTRYPOINT ["/start"]

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/cron start
```

Can anyone suggest where am I going wrong ?
I tried starting cron using "RUN service cron start" inside Dockerfile. That also did not work.

Comment: What's the image you use?

Comment: I am using base image FROM httpd:2.4

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite your cron records like this:

```
30 9    * * *   /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a public httpd image the answer is ultra simple...

There is no log written in these images as it's a bad practice, all logs are going to stdout and stderr allowing the container to have a volume for logs.

This also allow the facilitation of getting logs for other tools.